How do I create a transition between 2 different font awesome icons?
I have this button in HTML:
<button id="sidebar-toggle-button" class="btn btn-primary header-btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
      data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
      <div class="icons">
        <i id="sidebar-toggle-default" class="fa-solid fa-bars sidebar-toggle-icon-default"></i>
        <i id="sidebar-toggle-active" class="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered sidebar-toggle-icon-active"></i>
      </div>
    </button>

It's part of a collapsible sidebar that I made with Bootstrap (officially called an offcanvas). When I hover my mouse over this, I want the "sidebar-toggle-default" icon to transition to the "sidebar-toggle-active"icon.
I found this thread that tells me it's possible to do this with just CSS, but the effect is too complicated for what I'm trying to do, and I can't seem to replicate it in my own code either.
I want a very simple animation. The default icon is 3 bars stacked vertically, and the "active" icon below it is the same but the middle bar has a slight offset relative to the rest. When I hover over the icons, I want the transition to look like the middle bar is pushed forward. Is there a way to accomplish this?

"When I hover over the icons, I want the transition to look like the middle bar is pushed forward" FontAwesome icons are one complete image or SVG, so you wouldn't be able to move an individual portion. You can fade from the normal bars to the staggered bars, but it can't smoothly animate the motion of a single bar. (unless you recreate the original icon with individual bars yourself)

Do you really need it as a transition or will just replacing it with the staggered one do (the mind can make it seem like it was a continuous transition on such as small item).

This is quite an easy trick - put the second icon as position: absolute:


.icons {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  i {
    transition: opacity .4s;
    &:last-child {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}

.header-btn {
  &:hover {
    .icons {
      i {
        &:first-child {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        &:last-child {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="sidebar-toggle-button" class="btn btn-primary header-btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
  data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
  <div class="icons">
    <i id="sidebar-toggle-default" class="fa-solid fa-bars sidebar-toggle-icon-default"></i>
    <i id="sidebar-toggle-active" class="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered sidebar-toggle-icon-active"></i>
  </div>
</button>




Thanks! I set the transition duration to 0.1s and I think it looks perfect.
